# How I could insert an accented word in a new command?

Tags: macros, accents

I have the following command

```
\newcommand{\startsection}[4]{
\gdef\classname{#2}
\subsection*{\label{#3}{\bf {\sc #1} #2}}{
\rule[1em]{\hsize}{4pt}\vskip -1em
\vskip .1in 
#4
}%
}
```

I use it in the following way

```
\startsection{Anotaci\'on}{Lazy}{l0}
```

But my results is the following

Anotaci n Lazy

and my desired outpur would be something like this

Anotación Lazy

How I could solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Works for me. I suspect this is a problem with your small caps font. Please post a more complete Example (with preamble).

Comment: I'm guessing the font you are using doesn't have bold smallcaps ó. Most fonts don't include bold smallcaps at all, let alone accented characters.

Comment: @RoelofSpijker These are oldstyle LaTeX font switching commands. They don't combine like `\bfseries`, for instance.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Of course, you are right. So the problem most likely is that the smallcaps font is missing that accented character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\startsection}[4]{
\gdef\classname{#2}
\subsection*{\label{#3} \textbf{\textsc{#1} #2}}{
\rule[1em]{\hsize}{4pt}\vskip -1em \vskip .1in #4
}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\startsection{Anotaci\'on}{Lazy}{l0}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also pay attention for trailing spaces:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newcommand\startsection[4]{%
  \gdef\classname{#2}%
  \subsection*{\label{#3}\textbf{\textsc{#1} #2}}{%
  \rule[1em]{\hsize}{4pt}\vskip -1em \vskip .1in #4}}

\begin{document}
\startsection{Anotación}{Lazy}{l0}

\end{document}
```

[image]